# Start ssh automatically when restart docker container

Tags: docker, ssh

I am new to Nvidia-docker. I made a container and installed tones of Softwares in it. I can SSH to the container, but every time I restart the container, I need to restart the SSH service. I want to know how to start ssh automatically.
I saw similar problems on this question saying change my dockerfile, but I do not have a dockerfile...I created it using command and installed all Softwares in it, just consider my container like a normal Ubuntu.

---

Thank you for replying codingwithmanny. I am using Ubuntu, just using command prompt to operate. I feel my question is more like: if I did not setup autostart ssh when setting up the docker container, what should I do now to make it up?

Comment: Can you post the software that is running the commands, screenshots, and potentially which actions you took in the software?

Comment: You should probably split this up into a set of related images, each of which runs a single program, and has a Dockerfile committed to source control to build each of them.  Think of each container as the single program it's wrapping: in the same way you don't ssh into your browser, you don't generally ssh into a container.  An answer suggests `docker exec`; I'd recommend using that sparingly, for occasional debugging, and not as the primary way to use Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash` (or /bin/sh) instead of SSH server

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/
- https://medium.com/better-programming/docker-best-practices-and-anti-patterns-e7cbccba4f19

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, but I am doing my internship job, and this request is asked by my mentor. I am using exec now, while the project requires to use ssh.

Comment: I see, maybe its kind of tricky test? :) They ask you to do bad things and want to see your actions...

Comment: Btw, if its really a task which they want you to do, you may try to use something like linux services, here examples for linux alpine https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-enable-and-start-services-on-alpine-linux/. Alpine usually can be used for docker images. You may also search similar service for each linux dist.